# How to compute the average of a set of numbers inside a nested object within an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, big-o

I have the following object with a set of colors for each shape:

```
const design = {
      designId: 1,
      shapes: [
        { shapeId: 'basic-square', color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 }},
        { shapeId: 'basic-circle', color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 }},
        { shapeId: 'basic-diamond', color: { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 }},
        { shapeId: 'basic-rectangle', color: { r: 0, g: 255, b: 0 }}
      ]
    }
```

I want to return the following output which computes the average of each color per design object:

> Design 1: {r: 191.25, g: 191.25, b: 127.5 }

Keeping in mind Big O, what's the an efficient way to solve this problem?

Here is my attempt, however I was told it was not efficient enough:

```
const average = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length;

const { shapes } = design;

const reds = shapes.map(shape => shape.color.r)
const greens = shapes.map(shape => shape.color.g)
const blues = shapes.map(shape => shape.color.b)

console.log(`Design ${design.designId}: {r: ${average(reds)}, g: ${average(greens)}, b: ${average(blues)} }`)
```

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt.

Comment: It works the way you perform. What is the problem with your solution?

Comment: It works but I was told the way I did it was not good enough. I was curious how others might go about it.

Comment: For those who exploit, there is never "good enough".

Comment: You can avoid the duplicate `map()` calls, but O(3n) is O(n) so nit picking.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "exploit"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is O(6N) so it's O(N). I would've used a reduce however.

```js
const design = {
      designId: 1,
      shapes: [
        { shapeId: 'basic-square', color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 }},
        { shapeId: 'basic-circle', color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 }},
        { shapeId: 'basic-diamond', color: { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 }},
        { shapeId: 'basic-rectangle', color: { r: 0, g: 255, b: 0 }}
      ]
    };

const { shapes, designId  } = design;

const average = shapes.reduce((acc, curr) => ({
  red: acc.red + curr.color.r / shapes.length,
  green: acc.green + curr.color.g / shapes.length,
  blue: acc.blue + curr.color.b / shapes.length
  }), {
  red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0
  }
 );



console.log(`Design ${designId}: {r: ${average.red}, g: ${average.green}, b: ${average.blue}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is O(6n) (which is for all intents and purposes O(n)) but you can do it in O(1n) in a single `reduce()` call or `for` loop.

```js
const design = {
  designId: 1,
  shapes: [
    { shapeId: 'basic-square', color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 } },
    { shapeId: 'basic-circle', color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 } },
    { shapeId: 'basic-diamond', color: { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 } },
    { shapeId: 'basic-rectangle', color: { r: 0, g: 255, b: 0 } }
  ]
}

const sums = { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 };
for (const { color: { r, g, b } } of design.shapes) {
  sums.r += r
  sums.g += g;
  sums.b += b;
}

const len = design.shapes.length;
const result = {
  [`Design ${design.designId}`]: {
    r: sums.r / len,
    g: sums.g / len,
    b: sums.b / len
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and move the `Array.map()` part into the `average()` function

```js
const design = {
      designId: 1,
      shapes: [
        { shapeId: 'basic-square', color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 }},
        { shapeId: 'basic-circle', color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 }},
        { shapeId: 'basic-diamond', color: { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 }},
        { shapeId: 'basic-rectangle', color: { r: 0, g: 255, b: 0 }}
      ]
    };

//Design 1: {r: 191.25, g: 191.25, b: 127.5 }

function average(color) {
  let result = 0;
  for(let i=0; i<design.shapes.length; i++) {
    result += design.shapes[i].color[color]
  }
  return result / design.shapes.length;
}

console.log(`Design ${design.designId}: {r: ${average('r')}, g: ${average('g')}, b: ${average('b')} }`)
```